# Can someone explain what this algorithm question is asking for?

Tags: python, algorithm

I am new to writing algorithms for competitions. I got this question:[image]

I have written this so far:

```
import math 

def f(n):
    n1 = 0
    for row in str(n):
        n1 += math.factorial(int(row))
    return n1

def sf(n):
    n = f(n)
    n1 = 0
    for row in str(n):
        n1 += int(row)
    return n1
```

Can someone explain to me what this part of the question is asking for? (You do not need to write the code for it)
[image]

Comment: It says: Given a number `i`, find the smallest positive integer `n` for which `sf(n)==i`. Then `g(i)` is defined as that number `n`. So `g` is a kind of inverse of the function `sf`.

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense now.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's more of a comprehension/maths question than a programming question.